# Post loop created via shortcode not displaying shortcode in content

Tags: shortcode

I've been racking my brain on this. Here is a shortcode loop I've created to display a specific post type:

```
    function faq_shortcode($atts, $content = NULL) {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'faq_topic' => '',
            'faq_tag'   => '',
            'faq_id'    => '',
            'limit'     => '10',
        ), $atts));
        $faq_topic = preg_replace('~&#x0*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $faq_topic);
        $faq_tag = preg_replace('~&#x0*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $faq_tag);
            $faqs = new WP_Query(array(
                'p'                 => ''.$faq_id.'',
                'faq-topic'         => ''.$faq_topic.'',
                'faq-tags'          => ''.$faq_tag.'',
                'post_type'         =>  'question',
                'posts_per_page'    =>  ''.$limit.'',
                'orderby'           =>  'menu_order',
                'order'             =>  'ASC'
                ));
            $displayfaq= '<div class="faq_list">';
                while ($faqs->have_posts()) : $faqs->the_post();
                $displayfaq .= '<div class="single_faq">';
                $displayfaq .= '<h3 class="faq_question">'.get_the_title().'</h3>';
                $displayfaq .= '<p class="faq_answer">'.get_the_content().'</p>';
                $displayfaq .= '</div>';
                endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
            $displayfaq .= '</div>';
        return $displayfaq;
        }

add_shortcode('faq','faq_shortcode');
```

within one of those loops there is a post that has a shortcode being used

```
function emailbot_ssc($atts, $content = null) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'address' => '',
            ), $atts ) );
        ob_start();
        echo '<a href="mailto:'.antispambot($atts['address']).'" title="email us" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'.$atts['address'].'</a>';
        $email_ssc = ob_get_clean();
        return $email_ssc;
        }
add_shortcode("email", "emailbot_ssc");
```

the FAQ loop (code item #1) isn't parsing the shortcode. It just displays it raw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_the_content()` does not have the `the_content` filters applied to it, which is where `do_shortcode()` is hooked in. Those filters are only applied in `the_content()`. Those two functions are not simply get/echo versions of each other. `get_the_content()` is lower level.

This is an anomaly in the API, and is that way for historical reasons. For instance, `get_the_title()` applies the `the_title` filters.

If you want the whole `the_content` filter stack applied, do:

```
apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() )
```

If you *only* want shortcodes applied, do:

```
do_shortcode( get_the_content() )
```

Comment: That's what I assumed, and doing that doesn't seem to make a difference. If I put it outside that loop it doesn't chance anything, and if I put the it in the loop itself the content in the shortcode disappears completely.

Comment: [Some example code](https://gist.github.com/859c2c588403cb2cacf6).

Comment: That was it. I also realized I wasn't actually calling the 2nd shortcode correctly.